# I have a problem with getting a random image from my Json file

Tags: reactjs, json

So I have created a Json file with ID's and images of famous people. Now I would like to get a single random image out of the Json file and display it.

SO far I tried this, but I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image').

```
import images from "../Index.json"

function Celeb() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  let random = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];


    const handleNext = () => {
      console.log(images[1].image);
      setImage(images[random].image);
    }
    

  return (
    <div className='celeb'>
      <div className='celeb_buttons'>
        <button className='play_button' onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
   
      </div>
      <div className='pic'>
        <img src={image} />
      </div>
     </div>
```

If I replace the random in setImage(images[random].image) with 0 for example, I get the first image element out of the Json file, but I can not do it with random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random` is an image but you're trying to use it as a number later on.

```js
import images from "../Index.json"

function Celeb() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();

  const handleNext = () => {
    // Generate a random index in the images array
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

    // Use the random index to access the correct object in the images array
    // and set the image state to the value of the image property
    setImage(images[random].image);
  }

  return (
    <div className='celeb'>
      <div className='celeb_buttons'>
        <button className='play_button' onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
   
      </div>
      <div className='pic'>
        <img src={image} />
      </div>
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Works almost fine now. If I click the handleNext button, I get a random picture out of the Json file. But one problem I get now is, that I can click the button for a new picture a few times, but after that the button stops working and is not generating a new pic

Comment: @Brinda5 I missplaced the declaration of `random` variable. It should go outside of the `handleNext` function. I updated the snippet. Try now :)

Comment: I had it outside the function before. Now I placed the random inside of the function and it works. It now generates a new pic at random everytime I click the button. But thanks though

Comment: @Brinda5 alright, makes sense. Give a green tick if it works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

`random` is already an image. This `Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)` part generates a random index.

I don't see the structure of your json file, but I guess you have to change the setting part to

```
setImage(random.image);
```